# How can I reference three columns for an equation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a budget sheet using Google Forms and Google Sheets and want to learn how to total my expenditures. I have a column that has a timestamp, and from that I'd like to organize the data for the total by month. I also have an amount column and a type column that can either be incoming or outgoing. So, my goal is to have three different metrics for viewing my finances. First is to see total incoming money for the month. Second is to see total outgoing money for the month; and third is to view net gains.

[image: Image of spreadsheet]

To recap, how can I iterate through each row to see if it meets three requirements, and if it does, add it to a running total?

Comment: Try using `SUMIFS`?

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it'll work, but I'm confused on how to reference just the month in the timestamp cells.

Comment: Use `>=` and `<=` with the first and last days of the month.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.. So far I have `=SUMIFS(C2:C3,D2:D3,"Outgoing",A2:A3, ?? )`

Comment: https://productivityspot.com/google-sheets-sumifs-date-range/

Comment: Can you please clarify/specify and share a screenshot of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in G2 to get all unique months from Column A:

```
=unique(map(A2:A,lambda(x,if(x<>"",text(x,"MMM-YYYY"),""))))
```

[See the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8HU3.png)

Then use this formula to get sum of outgoing amount month wise:

```
=map($G$2:$G,lambda(x,if(x<>"",sum(iferror(FILTER($C$2:$C,$D$2:$D="Outgoing",text($A$2:$A,"MMM-YYYY")=x))),"")))
```

- In above formula, G2:G is the range in which your months are present
  after using the earlier formula.
- C2:C is the "Amount" range.
- D2:D is the "Type" range(this formula is for "Outgoing", change it to "Incoming" to get that sum).
- text() function convert your timestamp to month-year format.

Then you can use following formula to get the "Net Difference":

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if($G$2:$G<>"",$I$2:$I-$H$2:$H,""))
```

You need to use 4 formula is 4 cells only(G2,H2,I2,J2), see the image for reference(Highlighted cells):

[See the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNwne.png)